# Creating an OpenSearch Ingress service on Azure Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, opensearch

I'm trying to create an external IP address for an OpenSearch kubernetes service, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried following this Microsoft tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli to try and create an ingress service for OpenSearch. The ingress service yaml that I'm using is below.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: opensearch-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-dashboard-opensearch-dashboards
            port:
              number: 5601
      - path: /opensearch(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: opensearch-cluster-master
            port:
              number: 9200
---
```

The services are running, but when I go to the external IP address nothing loads.

[Kubernetes services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlAKf.png)

Is this an issue with the Ingress service, or is there another step that I need to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To create an OpenSearch Ingress service on AKS cluster, you can follow these steps:

1. Make sure you have an AKS cluster already set up and running.
2. Install an ingress controller in your AKS cluster. To install the NGINX ingress controller, you can follow the instructions provided in the official NGINX ingress controller documentation:  https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/
   here I am using helm

```bash
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
```

However if you want to expose your OpenSearch service to the outside world via a custom domain you can use something like this, just replace the hostname with your custom domain, but in that case you need to configure DNS records for your hostname to point to the external IP address of the ingress controller's load balancer.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: opensearch-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: opensearch.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: opensearch-service
                port:
                  number: 9200
```

I have deployed opensearch using helm

```bash
helm install my-release oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/opensearch
```

[image]
and named it as `my-release`
pods are up, port forwarded, dashboard can be accessed via [127.0.0.1:9200](http://127.0.0.1:9200/)

```bash
kubectl get pods
kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/my-release-opensearch 9200:9200
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

You can refer to below documents for further clarity

[Opensearch by Helm](https://bitnami.com/stack/opensearch/helm)

[Setup OpenSearch multi-node cluster on Kubernetes using Helm Charts](https://opensearch.org/blog/setup-multinode-cluster-kubernetes/)

[Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli)

[Opensearch user guide](https://github.com/Opster/opensearch-k8s-operator/blob/main/docs/userguide/main.md)

Comment: Do I need to have a custom domain to expose an external IP address? I tried to follow the Microsoft documentation you linked, but I cant seem to get it to work. I can do port forwarding and run OpenSearch locally just fine, but I need to have an external IP address available to other services I'm building. Could you please walk me through the exact steps to get my OpenSearch kubernetes service to work like Microsoft's example? Thank you so much!

Comment: No, you don't need to have a custom domain to expose an external IP address. You can use the external IP address of the ingress controller's load balancer to access your OpenSearch service from outside the cluster.